# The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})

Tags: java, android, listview, onclick, onclicklistener

Attempting to add an onClickListener to items in my listView and I'm getting an error stating: `"The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})"` on the line:

```
 holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

The author of this article mentioned the following:

```
In your custom adapter class, you can try this code inside getView() method
[java]holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked on image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
});[/java]
```

It seems as if I might need to modify my current implementation - I'm just not sure exactly how.

### Source:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item2, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtSuccess = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.success);
            holder.txtCmd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cmd);
            holder.txtPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked on image",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you probably have the wrong `import`. Check if you imported `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`. Still you can explicitly force the parameter this way:

```
holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
         Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked on image",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks! I just tried testing it and I don't get a toast... do you see anything else wrong with this:

http://pastebin.com/2pUHT0fq

Comment: you should move that logic outside the if(convertView == null){} and put it where do you actually set data

Comment: such as beneath holder.txtPrice.setText(cmd.getVideoURL() + ""); ?

http://pastebin.com/2pUHT0fq

Answer (score 0):

use `View.OnClickListener` instead of `OnClickListener` :

> ```
> holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
>                 public void onClick(View v) {
>                     Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked on image",
>                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>                 }
> ```

and use `CTL+SHIFT+O` to fix all imports